# Point limitation for PDL Gnuplot and QT terminal using replot

Tags: perl, gnuplot, pdl

While using PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot to plot data, I came across a strange effect. It seems, only a limited number of points is plotted at a time using `replot`.

Consider the following example (15 lines with 101 points):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDL;
use PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot qw/gpwin/;

my $win = gpwin('qt', persist => 1);

foreach my $a (1..15) {
    my $x = sequence(101)/100;

    my $y = $a*$x;

    if ($a == 1) {
        $win->plot({ linecolor => 'black' }, $x, $y);
    }
    else {
        $win->replot({ linecolor => 'black' }, $x, $y);
    }
}
```

Using this example, only 11 lines are plotted instead of 15.[image: using 101 points]

Reducing the number of points (from 101 to 51), 14 lines are plotted.
[image: using 51 points]

And finally using only 21 points, all 15 lines are displayed.

[image: using 21 points]

First, I thought only a limited number of lines is plotted, but this is not true since the number of plotted lines depend on the size of the piddles.

Is this a limit of the perl module or of Gnuplot? Is there a way to increase the number of maximum points? It seems to be a problem of Gnuplots qt version. Using `'x11'` as terminal does not show this limitation (I tested 100 lines with 101 points without any problems).

Further, I test the same example without using `replot` but in a single `plot`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDL;
use PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot qw/gpwin/;

my $win = gpwin('qt', persist => 1);

my $x = sequence(101)/100;
my $a = sequence(1,15)+1;
my $y = $x*$a;

$win->plot({ linecolor => 'black' }, $x, $y);
```

Using this code, everything works fine (even when increasing the number of lines to significantly larger values).

[image: 101 points in a single plot]

So finally, it seems to be an issue of the `replot` functionality of the `'qt'` terminal.

(G N U P L O T        Version 4.6 patchlevel 6)

Comment: This sounds like a bug. You should report it to the PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot maintainers [here](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=PDL-Graphics-Gnuplot).

Answer (score 1):

I've opened [an issue on PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot](https://github.com/PDLPorters/PDL-Graphics-Gnuplot/issues/88) - hopefully given Gnuplot is now on 5.4 this will not be a problem!